# How can Authentication be added to the Microsoft Bot Framework for a service provider such as Facebook when registering the Azure OAuth application

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying setup a the ability of using Facebook as a connection setting for a bot using the Microsoft bot framework. The issue is there isn't really any instruction from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript#register-the-azure-ad-oauth-application-with-the-bot) of how one would use other service providers such as Facebook, Google, Github and others.  Instead, the documentation is explanatory of AAD v1 and v2 settings.

The confusion comes at 2 points.

1. How to setup the Facebook developer app
2. What information to put into the Bot Framework web app bot -> settings for client id and client secret.

Comment: Regarding the issue, I think you need to register a web application in the Facebook developer portal.

Comment: i go it working i will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide the answer as there was a little confusion on how to set this up exactly.  [Here is an article that explains the process nicely.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-oauth)

The thing to keep in mind is that you don't have to do anything with an Active Directory Tenant i.e. create a `New App Registration`. That's where the confusion came from the [original documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript)

Instead, all you need to do is directly create an OAuth connection in the azure bot registered service. What is a registered app service? I'm glad you asked because this is the really tricky part you need to consider. Your bot is hosted in your Azure app service which is tied to an app service plan.

However, an interface of that service (think usually a website interface like front-end static files hosted on a server i.e. index.html) is called the Azure Web App and it's a registered service that is hosted in Azure and allows for connections to channels and OAuth interactions. Nothing really explains that nicely so I am explaining it here.

[You can read more about it here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

So why is that important? This is the place you go to open up your OAuth connection and create openings to other services such as Facebook, Linkedin, Github, Google and many more. Again, you don't need a new Registered Application for this in your tenant you just go directly to the Web App Service.

Once here you choose someone you setup such as Facebook and you use this callback url in the Facebook settings. `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`

And now, from your bot that is hosted on Azure it can communicate directly with other OAuth providers to return a token at no additional cost to you other than using the Web App service.

I hope this helps someone in the future.